# derivative with respective to the integral

Tags: calculus

Can some one give me some hints for obtaining the following result:
$$\frac{d}{du}(\int_{u}^{t}(x^2-u^2)^{\alpha}dx)=-u\left(\frac{(t^2-u^2)^{\alpha}}{t} +\int_{u}^{t}\frac{(x^2-u^2)^{\alpha}}{x^{2}}dx\right)$$

I do not know how to obtain this result.

Comment: Maybe calculus of variations? Or maybe just substitution? Have you tried that and not worked?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Try with Leibniz + Integration by parts

Comment: Thanks all your help and hints. Very useful. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

In general,
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) dt = f(x,b(x))b'(x) - f(x,a(x))a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)$$

In your case,
$$\frac{d}{du} \int_u^t(x^2-u^2)^\alpha dx = 0 - 0 + \int_u^t \frac{\partial}{\partial u} (x^2-u^2)^\alpha dx$$
Notice that if we assume that $x \neq 0$,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(x^2-u^2)^\alpha = - \frac{u}{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2-u^2)^\alpha$$
From here, integration by parts will give you what you need.

---

For our assumption to be valid, we must have that $u$ and $t$ must have the same sign.  Otherwise, our claim that $x\neq 0$ fails.

Comment: Thanks J. Murray for your kindly help. I got it. Really appreciate your help!